# Laravel Yajra is not accepting post/get request on query

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I am using Yajra data table. It's working fine until I decide to filter the result. For example: This is how my query looks like for Yajra (in controller)

```
if ($request->ajax()) {

        $data = product::get(); //SQL QUERY

        return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()                    
                ->addColumn('action', function($row){
 
                    $btn = '<a href="'.url('product/{'.base64_encode($row->id).'}').'" class="edit" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="'.url('/').'/export?product_id='.$row->id.'&productname='.$row->product_name.'"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';

                        return $btn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['image','discount','dt','action'])
                ->make(true);
    }
```

As you can see, this is how I defined sql query and it is working fine.

```
$data = product::get();
```

But later I decide to filter the result. I don't want to show all result but instead some result depending on the where condition with help of POST function.

So I replaced the previous query line with this one

```
 $data = product::select('*');
    
  //POST request
  if($request->has('vendor_list')){
    $data = $data->where('vendor', $request->vendor_list);
  }
       $data = $data->get();
```

To check if `$request->vendor_list` really has some value or not, I tried to print `$request->vendor_list` and value is getting printed. SO `$request->vendor_list` has value inside.

And when I try to manually add value instead of POST function in where condition then it started to work. Like this

```
$data = product::select('*');
$data = $data->where('vendor', 'vendor_name'); //MANUALLY typed value
$data = $data->get();
```

So not getting idea why yajra is not accepting value in where condition if I get value from GET or POST (both tried)?

> **UPDATE**

View File

```
<form action="" id="search_formm" method="GET">
    @csrf
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="search_box">
                <div id="category_wrap" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="form-group">  
                        <label>Select category</label>
                        <select name="category_list" id="category_list" class="form-control">
                          <option value="">Select</option>
                            @foreach($categories as $category)
                                <option value="{{$category->category_name}}" @if(request()->category_list == $category->category_name) selected @endif>{{$category->category_name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="vendor_wrap" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="form-group">  
                        <label>Select Vendor</label>
                        <select name="vendor_list" id="vendor_list" class="form-control">
                          <option value="">Select</option>
                            @foreach($vendors as $vendor)
                                <option value="{{$vendor->vendor_name}}" @if(request()->vendor_list == $vendor->vendor_name) selected @endif>{{$vendor->vendor_name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" id="search-btnn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
    <!--BELOW THIS FORM I AM USING YAJRA SCRIPT AND TABLE TAGS TO PRINT?SHOW ROWS FROM DB-->
```

Controller function

```
function productList(Request $request){
    if ($request->ajax()) {

        $data = product::select('*');

        if($request->has('category_name')){
            $data = $data->where('category', $request->category_name);
        }

        if($request->has('vendor_list')){
            $data = $data->where('vendor', $request->vendor_list);
        }

         $data = $data->get();

        return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('image', function($row){
                    if(!empty($row->product_image)){
                        $image = '<a href="'.asset('dashboard_assets/images/'.$row->product_image).'" target="_blank"><img src="'.asset('dashboard_assets/images/'.$row->product_image).'" height="60"></a>';
                    }else{
                        $image = 'NA';
                    }

                     return $image;
             })
                ->addColumn('dt', function($row){
 
                    $date = date("m/y", strtotime($row->created_at));

                     return $date;
             })
             ->addColumn('discount', function($row){
                
                if(!empty($row->product_discount)){
                    $discount = $row->product_discount.'%';
                }else{
                    $discount = 'NA';
                }

                 return $discount;
         })
                ->addColumn('action', function($row){
 
                    $btn = '<a href="'.url('product/{'.base64_encode($row->id).'}').'" class="edit" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="'.url('/').'/export?product_id='.$row->id.'&productname='.$row->product_name.'"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';

                        return $btn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['image','discount','dt','action'])
                ->make(true);
    }

    return view('products');
}
```

Comment: You're checking $request->has('***vendor***'), not ***vendor_list***.

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc Yes, I know. I have multiple POST values which I am receiving. Even if I remove if condition still Yajra is not letting me use any php variable or Post $request in where condition.

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc Even if Use store `$request->vendor_list` value in php variable and use that var in where like this `$data = $data->where('vendor',  $vendor);`, still it don't work. It seems yajra only accepts manual value in quote, not variable (in where condition).

Comment: try  $data = product::where('vendor', $request->vendor_list);

        return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn() so no need to call get since datatable  handle  that

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: @JohnLobo I will try your solution and let you know.

Comment: @omarjayed I am not getting any error. it's just it don't show any data if I add where clause with php variable.

Comment: @JohnLobo It didn't work. It don't take value from variable or `$request->anyname`. When we manually type value then it works

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you are trying to implement the `lazy loading` along with `real-time searching` with yajra datatables. For starters you do not have to use the `get()` as it will not implement the lazy loading. Yajra-datatable is smart enough to use it along with the searching by the column names.

However, you still have to do the searching manually, follow [this](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/manual-search). This is very straight-forward implementation.

Also if you plan on joing multiple database tables or your database table's column names names don't match with the datatable's column names, make sure both the column names are mapped properly. You can find a reference here.

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    
    var table = $('.yajra-datatable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "{{ route('product.list') }}", //or you can use the url with the parameters like /product/1 or prodcut?vendor=1
        columns: [
            {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'},
            {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'vendor', name: 'vendor'},
            {data: 'data_table_column', name: 'db_table_column'},
            .
            .
            {
                data: 'action', 
                name: 'action', 
                orderable: false, 
                searchable: false
            },
        ]
    });
```

That's kind of all you have to do. The rest (searching / sorting) will be taken care of the yajra-datables.

Now if you have any paramteres that you will have to pass with the url/request then get them. And check if they are empty or not.

```php
   $vendor = $request->vendor;
   $data = null;
   if(is_null($vendor)) {
      $data = Product::query();
   } else {
      $data = Product::where('vendor', $vendor);
   }
   
   return $data->....
```

Cause, if the vendor is `null` then laravel is checking if there's any `vendor` in the database that is equal to `null`. Nothing is matching and it's returning an empty object. Maybe that's why you aren't getting any errors, but also not getting any data either.

Comment: Hello sir, I tried your solution. Here is what I did, `$v = $request->vendor_list;`   `if(is_null($v)) {
            $data = product::get();
        }else{
            $data = product::where('vendor', $v);
        }` It is always going `if` condition, not in `else` condition. I tried to print value of `$v` and it is printing value. So `$v` has value. But thing is, Yajra is ignoring every php variable. It don't even consider php var. This is the main issue. Where there is php var, Yajra consider it as nothing.

Comment: Could you please tell me what you are trying to do with the request parameter? Is it a query string or url variable? And when is this issue coming? First time you load the page or when you search or sort data in the data-table?

Comment: I have a form with few fields. `action` of form is empty, means form is submitting on same page. When I submit then POST/GET (tried both) values I get. And I fetch them using `$request->form_field_name`. All values are of string type. When I try to print then with `echo` in controller (before yajara starts) then it is printing value. But inside yajra, it is being ignored by yajra. **Like yajra is saying:** `I won't be accepting any POST/GET values or any PHP variable. If you want me to use any value then type manually, do not store in variable or simillar.`

Comment: In my opinion, you might be using yajra in non-conventional way, probably not what yajra was built for. Yajra is meant to deal (search/sort/pagination) with data that are in a table (or in a version of it). But again, I may be wrong. If you have any shareable link to source code, please share. Also please update the post with view (with the form and where you want yajra to show data) and the full controller method.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post with `view` and `controller` as you asked for. Please check

Comment: Probably the problem is in the `input type="submit"`.  It submits the form and refreshes the page, hence you can see the input values in controller, but not in datatabel. Because it's not an ajax request and data tables are rendered only if it' an ajax request. Try submitting the form using ajax. That might solve the issue, or at least show the error; hopefully.

Comment: No, it doesn't seems to be the case. Bcoz when page refresh then datatable starts loading from start. Even if we think that datatable loads before the form submitted query data, Even then I also try to add `domain.com/page/?vendor_list=Elmo` directly in url. And fetch data from url instead of form. Still it don't give result. And its not possible that datatable ajax loads even before taking data from url.

Comment: Hi, I raised this issue on github also in page of owner of Yajra. He suggest me to use `query()` instead of `get()`. I tried but may couldn't make it work. Did you get idea what how he want it to be done? here is the url https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/2683

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
if($request->has('vendor_list')){
    $data = $data->whereRaw("`vendor` = '".$request->vendor_list."'");
}
```

Comment: H sir, I already tried that. The problem is, if condition will never gets true, because yajra ignores every `$request->anyname` and php variable. It only accept manually typed value, not php variable.

Comment: Can you please mention your JavaScript or jQuery code through you are sending POST request

Comment: HI, I am not sending POST request with JS. I am sending with simple laravel form. Default form submission without any JS involvement.

Answer (score 0):

You were right to change the `product::get();` as it returns a collection of all your items, and not a "SQL" (eloquent) instance. So all filtering wasn't done on the SQL query level.

If your input `vendor_list` is a string matching exactly a value in the `products.vendor` column value:

Could you try

```
    if(request()->has('vendor_list')){
        $data = $data->where('vendor', $request->input('vendor_list'));
    //if vendor_list is an array
    // $data = $data->whereIn('vendor', $request->input('vendor_list'));
    }

    //here you should apply some pagination to your query, based on the frontend datatable page parameter.
    $data = $data->get();
```

But as your input is named `vendor_list`: are you sending back an array? If so, you should use `$data->whereIn('vendor', $request->input('vendor_list'))`. If it's a string list vendor of vendor value like `vendor1,vendor2...`, explode it then `whereIn`, etc.

Comment: Hi sir, sadly `if` condition is never getting true. It always goes to `else` even if query var has value.

Comment: Please dump the `$request->input('vendor_list')` to be sure it contains a string that can be matched to a column value. I guess your issue comes from the input format.

Comment: Can you also dump something like `request()->all()` to double-check input format?

Comment: I try to store one query value and did `dump` with `request()->all()` and received this `array(1) { ["vendor_list"]=> string(4) "Elmo" }`. I did `dumb` before yajara code starts (first line of controller function. Although it printed mentioned array but yajra table gave error in alert `invalid json response` and store displaying rows in table. When I remove `dump` then table rows starting to appear again.

Comment: Ok so the input seems correct. The `Elmo` value will match something in your DB? Can you try dumping the `request()->has('vendor_list')` ? as it should return true if the payload is the only you dumped.

Comment: Yes it is showing value fine. Even when I try to echo like this `echo $request->vendor_list`, then it is printing value. But issue is, yajra is not accepting value. Kinda **Yajra saying:** `Give me only manually typed value. Do not even try to give me php variable or any POST/GET method values. I won't accept it..` What to do :(

Comment: Thing is Yajra accepts an Eloquent query, or a collection. So this basic Laravel query should be accepted as any other SQL query. Can you try removing the `$data->get();` so Yajra get a Eloquent instance, and not a Collection of data?

Comment: No, it is not like that. `$data->get();` is not an issue here. Because if I use `where` clause like this `$data = $data->where('vendor', 'Elmo');` then it give result correctly becoz I manually typed value in `where` clause. But if I type any variable or query menthod in where like this `$data = $data->where('vendor', $request->vendor_list);` then it don't give result. So if `$data->get()` would be the issue then it should not be running when I manually type value in `where` clause.

Comment: Hi, I raised this issue on github also in page of owner of Yajra. He suggest me to use `query()` instead of `get()`. I tried but may couldn't make it work. Did you get idea what how he want it to be done? here is the url https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/2683

Comment: Yes, I also told you to ` removing the $data->get(); so Yajra gets an Eloquent instance`. When you do a `->get()` you have a collection of items, and no more an eloquent/sql query. Yajra datatables accepts eloquent instances, so it can apply filter, pagination, etc... directly. So you need to pass to `Datatable::of` an eloquent instance. What happens when you try this?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use `query()` instead of `get()`. But problem is, `if` condition to check if query variable has any value, never gets true. For example: `if ($request->vendor_list) {` this `if` condition I put so that if there is any data available with `$request->vendor_list` only then run `where` clause, this one `$data ->where('vendor', $request->vendor_list);`. But said thing is, if condition never gets true and this results in, code inside `if` condition gets ignored every time. Don't know what to do :(

Comment: I dont get how this simple IF is not working... As you working on multiple servers? or CRON based?

Comment: Well for now, m doing testing on localhost (xampp). Just out of curiosity, did you try something like in you project earlier? was it fine on your end? Asking coz want to know if it is issue of Yajra of something wrong on my end.

Comment: Yes I used Yajra datatables a lot, with Collection at first, and then with eloquent query so Yjara handle itself pagination and stuff like this. But your issue seems not to be related to Yajra directly, as it's a perfectly simple if/else tat fails in your case.... an you test on another controller and method, or another file, if the if/else works with a POST request? like a simple form POC

Comment: I don't know then what causing it, I am so confused...  It's just Yajra not taking value from `$request->field_name`. Even without if condition `where` clause don't work if I use `$request->field_name`. But if I type custom value instead of query var then it works. I have no idea whats going on with my project... Damn thats seems impossible now to get rid of this issue. Can you (as final attempt) pls have a look on my previously given github link. There in last comment I have pasted my whole code which I have used for datatable to check if there something that I missed..

Comment: Can you try by storing `$request->input('field_name`) in a variable, Log::info() it, and then use it in the if() statement?

Comment: Hi, I didn't solve my issue. May be issue is not from code but from somewhere else (don't know where). However, time of bounty expiring now so I am rewarding you with bounty for staying connected with me till last. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Ho, that is kind of you, thanks a lot. We can continue trying: have you tried storing the request input in a variable, Log it, then use it for the eloquent request? That way by checking the logs you are sure of the input value at the time of the eloquent condition. As your issue seems to come from a basic "if" and "request" input helper...